# Why is freezing something "fast enough" be approximated as adiabatic?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

I am reading Scott Shell's *Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics*, and I just saw this statement:

> If freezing happens fast enough, to a good approximation the process can be considered adiabatic.

The author has mentioned this statement while talking about a problem regarding the spontaneous freezing of subcooled water at $-10^{\circ}$C.

Why is this the case? I thought freezing is a constant temperature, constant pressure phenomenon. When you freeze something, a certain amount of heat $Q$ is removed from it and it escapes into an environment of some temperature $T$. How can freezing ever be adiabatic?

Comment: I am no expert, but is it possible that it's just a mistake? Your argument seems pretty reasonable to me. What does the author use this fact for? Maybe with some context someone could say what the author meant.

Comment: @Javier, perhaps. I have added some extra context to the question, maybe that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the liquid water starts out sub-cooled at -10 C, it is not at thermodynamic equilibrium, and there is a driving force for it to change spontaneously into a mixture of liquid water and ice at 0 C.  Its own heat of freezing provides the energy necessary to bring about this change at constant enthalpy.  There is no need to remove heat from the system by transferring it to the surroundings.

Heat transfer is a process that takes time to occur, and the amount of heat transferred increases with both the temperature difference between the surroundings and the system, and the amount of time available for the heat to be transferred.  In this case, the process takes place very rapidly, and even if there is a temperature difference between the surroundings and the system (assuming, for example, the surroundings are at 0 C), there is not enough time for a significant amount of heat to be transferred.

**Response**

Let M represent the amount of liquid water at -10 C and let m be the amount of ice resulting at 0 C, and (M-m) the amount of liquid water at 0 C.

Take as a reference state for calculating enthalpy, liquid water at 0 C.  Then, per unit mass relative to the reference state, the enthalpy per unit mass of the liquid water at -10 C is $$h=MC(-10-0)=-10MC$$ where C is the heat capacity of liquid water.

In the final state, the enthalpy per unit mass of the ice is $$h=-m\Delta H_f$$where $\Delta H_f$ is the latent heat of fusion of ice.  And the enthalpy per unit mass of the liquid water is $$h=(M-m)C(0-0)=0$$
So applying the first law of thermodynamics to this system with Q = 0 (adiabatic) yields:  $$-10MC=-m\Delta H_f$$

Comment: If I have $M$ kg of subcooled water at -10 C, and 1 atm pressure, let's say $m$ kg of it becomes ice. Let $L$ be the heat of freezing, $C_{p,i}$ be the heat capacity of ice, and $C_{p,w}$ be the heat capacity of water. If we are heading to equilibrium, we will have ice + water at 0 C. Thinking about how the heat transfer looks like,

Comment: subcooled water -10 C +H1 -> subcooled water at 0 C -Q1-> ice + water at 0 C, if this process if isenthalpic, does this mean that H1 = - Q1? where $H1 = MC_{p,w}\Delta T$, $Q1 = mL$ where L is the latent heat of freezing. Is this the right train of thought?

Comment: I think you would get the right answer, but that's not how I would set it up.  See the Response I have added to my answer.

Comment: The argument only works because the water is not in equilibrium, right? Otherwise, if the process was reversible, the freezing wouldn't conserve entropy (and thus couldn't be adiabatic **and** reversible). Is that right?

Comment: If it is attaining equilibrium, that has to mean entropy is being maximized. I dont think this process is entropy conserving...

Comment: @ChetMiller, how would you calculate the entropy change of the system and the surrounding as the water partially freezes? As subcooled water goes from -10 to 0, you can use $C_p \ln(T_2/T_1)$ and when it freezes, i can say $\Delta S = Q/T$. But in this process, the entropy of the surroundings remains unchanged, right?

Comment: I get $MC\ln{(273/263)}-\frac{mL}{273}$.  And, yes, the change in entropy of the surroundings is zero.